# A series involving spectrum of $- \Delta_{\mathbb{S}^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence

Infinite series involving eigenvalues of the Beltrami-Laplace operator on Riemannian manifolds as well as $L^p$-estimates of eigenfunctions arise in  the study of the nonlinear Schrödinger equation (NLS) on compact manifolds (for instance $M = \mathbb{S}^2$). Denote by $\mu_{k} := k(k + 1)$  the eigenvalue of the operator 
$- \Delta_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ associated to the eigenfunction $e_k \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Now, consider the summation
$$  \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \langle \mu_k - \alpha  \rangle \langle \mu_k \rangle^{\varepsilon}}$$ where $\alpha > 0$ (is a positive arbitrary constant), $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\langle x \rangle : = 1 + |x|$. My question is the following:

$$\langle \mu_k - \alpha \rangle^{-1} \langle \mu_k \rangle^{- \varepsilon} \in \ell^{1}_{k}(\mathbb{N}) \mbox{ }, $$

independently of the choice of $ \alpha$?

My failed attempt was to consider two cases: (Case 1) $\mu_k \geq 4 \alpha$. In this case we have $|\mu_k - \alpha| \geq \frac{3}{4} \mu_k$ and one can obtain  the desired conclusion. (Case 2) $\mu_k \leq 4 \alpha$. In this case, we have a finite sum, but I would like to prove that the summation is bounded by a constant which does not depends on $\alpha$. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Eigenvalues of $-\Delta_{S}$ have nothing to do with this. What you are trying to prove is whether there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $$\|(k^2-\alpha)k^{2\epsilon}\|_{\ell^1_k}\le C, $$ where the sum starts at $k=1$. But this is clearly impossible. As $\alpha\to \infty$, the left-hand side tends to infinity, too.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326987/let-alpha-0-and-varepsilon-0-then-sum-n-0-infty-frac1

Comment: Oh right, what I said about alpha going to infinity is incorrect. Sorry.